# count record of one type and record overall in a query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table like this:

```
User        Length WHO     Bay
DOMISLOVICM 69,272 1061840 3
GASPARICM   58,608 1060570 5
GASPARICM   1,3    1060571 3
...
```

I wanted to count how many record have a lenght greater than 5 in each different bay. To do so I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT Bay, Count(*) as Occurrences FROM Table
WHERE Length>5 group by Bay;
```

This works perfect, and in the above case it would return:

```
Bay Occurrences
3   1
5   1
```

Now I have been asked to extend the query to include, for each bay, also the number of total records that are in the table for each bay, including those whose length isn't over 5. The result for the example table should be:

```
Bay Occurrences Totals
3   1           2
5   1           1
```

Because I have 3 record in total for Bay 3 and 1 for Bay 5.
How do I extend the query?
If I use the where clause to delimit records to those with length over 5, I cannot use count(*) to count overall record... any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**EDIT:** This is SQL Server Syntax, if it does not work on your DB let me know.

```
SELECT Bay, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Length > 5 THEN 1 END) as Occurrences,
    COUNT(*) as Totals
FROM Table
GROUP BY Bay;
```

**EDIT :** Like @HansUp suggested in the comment, the correct Access syntax to accomplish this is `SUM(IIF([Length] > 5, 1, 0))`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Database is Access (actually I'm running analisys on tables extracted from SAP), your query gives error because of a missing operator in SUM clause;

Comment: In Access, use `IIf` instead of `CASE WHEN`.  Try it this way: `Sum(IIf([Length] > 5, 1, 0)) AS Occurrences`

Comment: Like charm! This one worked perfectly, I have to study aggregate functions... :)